# What is this error `make.exe": no_c_compiler: Command not found`

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw, zlib

I'm trying to build [grpc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/) from source on Windows 2012 Server edition. I downloaded and installed Python 3.5 from the Python website and installed the entire MinGW package as well as git along with git bash. Following the instructions for building from source:

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
 $ cd grpc
 $ git submodule update --init
 $ make
 $ [sudo] make install
```

I get the aforementioned error after executing make. Here's the shell output for your perusal.

```
PS C:\Users\thunderboltsid\grpc> make
[MAKE]    Generating /c/Users/thunderboltsid/grpc/libs/opt/pkgconfig/grpc.pc
[MAKE]    Generating /c/Users/thunderboltsid/grpc/libs/opt/pkgconfig/grpc_unsecure.pc
[MAKE]    Generating cache.mk
[C]       Compiling third_party/zlib/adler32.c
make.exe": no_c_compiler: Command not found
make.exe": *** [/c/Users/thunderboltsid/grpc/objs/opt/third_party/zlib/adler32.o] Error 127
```

I really can't understand what is this error supposed to be. Tried googling but that didn't help. Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Going through the Makefile, it looks like `which gcc`, `which cc`, and `which clang` all come up empty, which version of mingw did you install exactly?

Comment: @user657267 That'd be v4.9.3-1. You're correct about all the which commands coming up empty. When I try to run `which`, the shell throws an error saying it's not a recognized cmdlet, function, or script file.

Comment: Searching through the MinGW installation, I can find a file of type file called `which` under `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`

Comment: If you installed mingw I'd suggest you remove it and install mingw-w64 with MSYS2, I'm not sure why it can't find `which`, maybe the PATH variable isn't set correctly? You may also be able to work around the issue by running `make DEFAULT_CC=gcc DEFAULT_CXX=g++`.

Comment: Can you execute `env` from your msys? I guess some environmental variables are not properly set.

Answer (score 5):

you may need run `apt-get install which`

Comment: Kindly elaborate the answer

Comment: This is actually this corret answer. Why did someone downvote it? I went into a similar problem compiling grpc in a Docker image. The error message was cryptic and it turned out that `which` was not installed in the image.

Answer (score 0):

install build-base in your system, example:

```
apt-get install build-base
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply have no C compiler installed, not even gcc. If that's the reason then installing gcc resolves the issue:

```
apt get install gcc
```

Comment: `no_c_compiler: Command not found` does not mean there's no c compiler, it literally means the command `no_c_compiler` is missing. Installing `which` indeed resolves the issue because `no_c_compiler` relies on it.